# Trie implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, trie

I have created a trie in Python and am looking for feedback.  Specifically, I am looking for feedback on:

1. If my code is 'pythonic'
2. If my logic is proper when inserting and retrieving from the trie

I have implemented the following logic:

1. Insert a word into the trie
2. Check if a word exists in the trie
3. Given a prefix, get all possible words
   . Get all the words in the trie

My purpose for coding the trie is to improve my Python and algorithm knowledge.

```
from collections import deque


class Node:
    def __init__(self, character, parent):
        self.character = character
        if self.character is not None:
            self.character = self.character.lower()
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = dict()
        self.terminus = False

    def add(self, child_node):
        self.children[child_node.character] = child_node


class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = Node(None, None)

    def insert(self, word):
        if word:
            current_node = self._root
            for i, character in enumerate(self._normalize_word(word)):
                if character in current_node.children:
                    current_node = current_node.children[character]
                else:
                    child_node = Node(character, current_node)
                    current_node.add(child_node)
                    current_node = child_node
            current_node.terminus = True

    def __contains__(self, item):
        current_node = self._root
        contained = True
        for symbol in self._normalize_word(item):
            if symbol in current_node.children:
                current_node = current_node.children[symbol]
            else:
                contained = False
                break
        return contained and current_node.terminus

    def _normalize_word(self, word):
        return word.strip().lower()

    def _get_all_words(self, prefix, node, word_list):
        if node.character:
            prefix.append(node.character)
        for child in node.children.values():
            self._get_all_words(prefix, child, word_list)
        if node.terminus:
            word_list.append("".join([i[0] for i in prefix]))
        if len(prefix) > 0:
            prefix.pop()

    def get_possible_words(self, prefix):
        current_node = self._root
        found_prefix = True
        word_list = []
        prefix_deque = deque()
        for symbol in prefix.strip().lower():
            if symbol in current_node.children:
                current_node = current_node.children[symbol]
            else:
                found_prefix = False
                break
        if found_prefix:
            self._get_all_words(prefix_deque, current_node, word_list)
            # This is a bit kludgy - add the prefix to the rest of the characters found,
            # but I take off the last character from the prefix because it was added
            # in the _get_all_words method call since it is the current_node being passed into it. 
            # Is there a better way to do this?
        word_list = list(map(lambda word: prefix[:len(prefix)-1] + word, word_list))

        return word_list

    def get_all_words(self):
        word_list = []
        self._get_all_words(deque(), self._root, word_list)
        return word_list
```

Here is my unit test:

```
import unittest
from algorithms import trie


class TestTrie(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #            root
        #          /      \
        #       /           \
        #     a *             b
        #    / \             /
        #   d   n *         a
        #  /   / \       /  |  \
        # d * d * y *   g * t *  y *
        #              / \   \
        #             e   s * h *
        #            /
        #           l *
        # asterisk denotes a word

        cls._trie = trie.Trie()
        cls._trie.insert("a")
        cls._trie.insert("add")
        cls._trie.insert("an")
        cls._trie.insert("and")
        cls._trie.insert("any")
        cls._trie.insert("bagel")
        cls._trie.insert("bag")
        cls._trie.insert("bags")
        cls._trie.insert("bat")
        cls._trie.insert("bath")
        cls._trie.insert("bay")

        cls._trie_length = 11 # magic number, the number of words in the trie

    def test(self):
        assert len(self._trie.get_all_words()) == self._trie_length

        assert "a" in self._trie
        assert "add" in self._trie
        assert "an" in self._trie
        assert "and" in self._trie
        assert "any" in self._trie
        assert "bagel" in self._trie
        assert "bag" in self._trie
        assert "bags" in self._trie
        assert "bat" in self._trie
        assert "bath" in self._trie
        assert "bay" in self._trie

    def test_duplicate_entries(self):
        """Adding a word that already exists should not create a new word in the trie"""
        t = self._trie
        t.insert("bag")

        assert len(t.get_all_words()) == self._trie_length
        assert "bag" in t

    def test_mixed_case(self):
        """insert and retrieval are case insensitive"""
        t = trie.Trie()
        t.insert("APPLE")
        t.insert("oRANge")

        assert "apple" in t
        assert "orange" in t

        assert "APPLE" in t
        assert "ORANGE" in t

        assert "aPpLe" in t
        assert "oRangE" in t

    def test_hyphenated_words(self):
        t = trie.Trie()
        t.insert("e-mail")
        t.insert("above-said")
        t.insert("above-water")
        t.insert("above-written")
        t.insert("above")
        t.insert("abode")
        t.insert("exit")

        assert len(t.get_all_words()) == 7

        assert "abode" in t
        assert "above" in t
        assert "above-written" in t
        assert "above-water" in t
        assert "above-said" in t
        assert "e-mail" in t
        assert "exit" in t

    def test_empty_trie(self):
        t = trie.Trie()
        assert len(t.get_all_words()) == 0

    def test_first_symbol_is_a_word(self):
        t = trie.Trie()
        t.insert("a")
        t.insert("apple")

        assert "a" in t
        assert "apple" in t

        words = t.get_all_words()
        assert len(words) == 2
        assert "a" in words
        assert "apple" in words

    def test_get_possible_words(self):
        prefix = 'an'
        expected_words = ['an', 'and', 'any']
        actual_words = self._trie.get_possible_words(prefix)
        assert len(expected_words) == len(actual_words)
        for word in expected_words:
            assert word in actual_words

        prefix = 'ba'
        expected_words = ["bagel", "bag", "bags", "bat", "bath", "bay"]
        actual_words = self._trie.get_possible_words(prefix)
        assert len(expected_words) == len(actual_words)
        for word in expected_words:
            assert word in actual_words

    def test_get_possible_words_no_more_words(self):
        """test that given a prefix that is a terminus with no children in the trie, returns that one word"""
        prefix = 'any'
        actual_words = self._trie.get_possible_words(prefix)
        assert len(actual_words) == 1
        assert prefix in actual_words

    def test_get_possible_words_prefix_not_in_trie(self):
        prefix = 'z'
        actual_words = self._trie.get_possible_words(prefix)
        assert len(actual_words) == 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting in the `Node` class, there was a `parent` attribute that never gets referenced.  Also I find if you are just assigning a variable based off one condition doing it in one line makes the code cleaner and easier to read.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, character):
        self.character = character if character is None else character.lower()
        self.children = dict()
        self.terminus = False

    def add(self, child_node):
        self.children[child_node.character] = child_node
```

In your `Trie` class specifically with the `.insert` and `__contains__` methods:

```
def insert(self, word):
    if word: # checking for truth to continue
        current_node = self._root
        for i, character in enumerate(self._normalize_word(word)):
            if character in current_node.children:
                current_node = current_node.children[character]
            else:
                child_node = Node(character, current_node)
                current_node.add(child_node)
                current_node = child_node
        current_node.terminus = True
```

You can save a level of indentation by returning on false, essentially short-circuiting your method:

```
def insert(self, word):
    if not word:
        return
    current_node = self._root
    for i, character in enumerate(self._normalize_word(word)):
        if character in current_node.children:
            current_node = current_node.children[character]
        else:
            child_node = Node(character, current_node)
            current_node.add(child_node)
            current_node = child_node
    current_node.terminus = True
```

You also make a call to `enumerate` but never use it:

```
def insert(self, word):
    if not word:
        return
    current_node = self._root
    for character in self._normalize_word(word):
        if character in current_node.children:
            current_node = current_node.children[character]
        else:
            child_node = Node(character, current_node)
            current_node.add(child_node)
            current_node = child_node
    current_node.terminus = True
```

Seeing your logic in your method made me think you could also have used a recursive method, something along the lines of:

```
def insert(self, word):
    if not word: 
        return
    self.__insert(self._normalize_word(word), self._root).terminus = True

def __insert(self, word, node):
    if not word:
        return node
    elif {word[0]} & node.children.keys():
        return self.__insert(word[1:], node.children[word[0]])
    else:
        new_node = Node(word[0])
        node.add(new_node)
        return self.__insert(word[1:], new_node)
```

One other change I made which depending on the size of the tree will improve performance is the use of a logical `&` on the `children.keys()`.  [PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) brought about [changes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-3106-dictionary-views) that allowed for set operations on dict-keys.  This means you could just as well check if a dict has a value as a key by `{value} & dict.keys()` rather than iterating over every key.

In the `__contains__` method where you set a truth flag to false then `break` and then test with a logical `&`:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    current_node = self._root
    contained = True
    for symbol in self._normalize_word(item):
        if symbol in current_node.children:
            current_node = current_node.children[symbol]
        else:
            contained = False
            break
    return contained and current_node.terminus
```

If `contained` is set to `False` theres no need to check at the bottom of the method.  Just get rid of `contained` and return `False` if your first condition isn't met.  Similar to the last point in `.insert` you can save a couple of lines if you short-circuit, basically no need for `else` if you are returning on it:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    current_node = self._root
    for symbol in self._normalize_word(item):
        if symbol not in current_node.children:
            return False
        current_node = current_node.children[symbol]
    return current_node.terminus
```

I saw this as another place where you could have done this recursively as well:

```
def __contains(self, word, node):
    if not word:
        return node
    return self.__contains(word[1:], node.children[word[0]]) if \
           {word[0]} & node.children.keys() else None

def __contains__(self, item):
    word = self._normalize_word(item)
    return self.__contains(word, self._root) is not None
```

In the `__contains` method you can return the `Node` of the last letter or `None`.  This is useful where you can get a boolean value from your dunder-contains method to check for membership but also you can use the `__contains` method with the `get_possible_words` method later.  This is similar to how I adjusted the `__insert` method to return the final `Node` after inserting to set `.terminus`.

```
def get_possible_words(self, word):
    word_node = self.__contains(word, self._root)
    return [] if word_node is None else \
           self.__get_possible_words(word, word_node)
```

Here you can get your final `Node` and that will be the starting point to retrieve all possible words.  If its `None` just return an empty `list` else:

```
def __get_possible_words(self, word, word_node, word_list=None):
    word_list = [] if word_list is None else word_list
    if word_node.terminus:
        word_list.append(word)
    for letter in word_node.children:
        if not word_node.children[letter]:
            word_list.append(word + letter)
        else:
            self.__get_possible_words(word + letter,
                                      word_node.children[letter], word_list)
```

And putting it altogether:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, character):
        self.character = character if character is None else character.lower()
        self.children = dict()
        self.terminus = False

    def add(self, child_node):
        self.children[child_node.character] = child_node


class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = Node(None) 

    def insert(self, word):
        if not word: 
            return
        self.__insert(self._normalize_word(word), self._root).terminus = True

    def __insert(self, word, node):
        if not word:
            return node
        elif {word[0]} & node.children.keys():
            return self.__insert(word[1:], node.children[word[0]])
        else:
            new_node = Node(word[0])
            node.add(new_node)
            return self.__insert(word[1:], new_node)

    def __contains(self, word, node):
        if not word:
            return node
        return self.__contains(word[1:], node.children[word[0]]) if \
               {word[0]} & node.children.keys() else None

    def __contains__(self, item):
        word = self._normalize_word(item)
        return self.__contains(word, self._root) is not None

    def _normalize_word(self, word):
        return word.strip().lower()

    def get_possible_words(self, word):
        word_node = self.__contains(word, self._root)
        return [] if word_node is None else \
               self.__get_possible_words(word, word_node)

    def __get_possible_words(self, word, word_node, word_list=None):
        word_list = [] if word_list is None else word_list
        if word_node.terminus:
            word_list.append(word)
        for letter in word_node.children:
            if not word_node.children[letter]:
                word_list.append(word + letter)
            else:
                self.__get_possible_words(word + letter,
                                          word_node.children[letter], word_list)
        return word_list

    def get_all_words(self):
        word_list = []
        for letter in self._root.children:
            word_list.extend(self.get_possible_words(letter))
        return word_list
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @tijko. I did not know about PEP 3106 so it is great to learn about it. The code looks much more condensed. Thank you!